# Query String to C# Object in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf

I have a very generic question.

When Developing with ASP.NET MVC. It provides a great way to utilize C# to interact with Client side objects like Query string.

I wanted to know how does ASP.NET MVC Framework converts Query String sent in GET request or Form Data in POST request to a Strongly Typed C# class? Are there any specific HttpHandler or HttpModules for this? Or are they using any Pre-Defined Action Filter?

I want to implement similar feature in WCF based RESTFull services. I believe I will need to use Interceptor for this purpose.

Please provide some advice.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're referring to [ASP.NET MVC Model Binding.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410405.aspx)  This is actually a completely separate part of the framework than `ActionFilters` or HttpModules.  It works by examining "value providers" - the sources of information in the request, like form data, the query string, or even the route - and attempting to match them by name to properties in the complex type in your controller action.

As Kenneth mentioned, you can check out the source on [CodePlex](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/), but if you're looking to write services using RESTful architectural patterns you can start using the [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) features in the MVC4 beta, which also supports model binding (so you won't have to reinvent it!)

It's also worth mentioning that the Web API was being developed for WCF but is now a part of [ASP.NET MVC](http://wcf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WCF%20Web%20API%20is%20now%20ASP.NET%20Web%20API), which makes sense since ASP.NET MVC, like the Web API, are both built primarily around HTTP.

Comment: Thanks Brandon, It is nice advice and very insightful explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with the wcf extensibility model, but on the mvc3 side, all the source is out there.  You can see exactly how Model binding is implemented.  Just download the source, its a rather informative read.

http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/58781